# Figuring out lifetime for reference from a consumed value

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have some code that, simplified, looks like this:

```
enum A<'a> {
    AConst(&'a [u8])
}

trait FromA {
    fn from_a(A) -> Self;
}

impl FromA for &[u8] {
    fn from_a(a: A) -> &[u8] {
        match a {
            AConst(bytes) => bytes
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // I'd like to use it like this:
    let s = b"abc";
    let a = AConst(s);
    let foo: &[u8] = from_a(a);
}
```

This doesn't work, as the compiler complains about missing lifetime specifiers on the `&[u8]`. Now I'm not sure what the correct lifetime would be. As `from_a` consumes its argument, the lifetime of the returned reference clearly cannot be the same as the lifetime of the argument.

Is it possible to somehow use lifetime annotations to achieve this? If it is, what would the correct annotations be? Can we somehow make the `A` type carry information about the lifetime of the reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can we somehow make the `A` type carry information about the lifetime of the reference?

That is in fact exactly what you are doing when writing

```
enum A<'a> {                                //'
    AConst(&'a [u8])                        //'
}
```

The full type here is `A<'a>` meaning that `A` carries inside it a reference of lifetime `'a`.

To be correct, you need to propagate explicitly this lifetime in your trait definition and implementation :

```
trait FromA<'a> {                           //'
    fn from_a(A<'a>) -> Self;               //'
}

impl<'a> FromA<'a> for &'a [u8] {           //'
    fn from_a(a: A<'a>) -> &'a [u8] {
        match a {
            AConst(bytes) => bytes
        }
    }
}
```

Thus saying : The lifetime of the `&[u8]` slice is the lifetime of the reference contained in the `A` object.

You can then do :

```
fn main() {
    let s = b"abc";
    let a = AConst(s);
    let foo: &[u8] = FromA::from_a(a);
    println!("{}", foo);
}

[97, 98, 99]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I tried something along those lines, but I must have missed one of the annotations and the error message confused me.